# DataFrame not filling with value generate from Loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am running a for loop in order to create a dataframe of 'New' values.

```
New = 0
Approved = 0
df = pd.DataFrame()
for row, rowdata in enumerate(combined):
    for col, value in enumerate(rowdata.values()):
        if col == 0:
            print(value)
        if col == 2:
            New += value
            print('Original New')
            print(value)
        if col == 4:
            Approved = value
            if Approved > 0:
                New = New - Approved
            print('Updated New')
            print(New)
        df['New'] = New
```

Everything in this code seems to be working except for the last `df['New'] = New` statement. Any ideas on why that might be happening would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df['New'] = New` is a wrong way to insert a single row.

#### One way to fix it:

```
all_rows = []
New = 0
Approved = 0
for row, rowdata in enumerate(combined):
    for col, value in enumerate(rowdata.values()):
        if col == 0:
            print(value)
        if col == 2:
            New += value
            print('Original New')
            print(value)
        if col == 4:
            Approved = value
            if Approved > 0:
                New = New - Approved
            print('Updated New')
            print(New)
        # Accumulate all the rows
        all_rows.append(New)
# Finally create a dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({'New': all_rows})
```

Comment: if I wanted to add Approved to the new dataset and have associated with the new values they pair with, how would I go about that?

Comment: Add all approved to `all_approveds` list and finally `df = pd.DataFrame({'New': all_rows, 'Approved': all_approveds})`